# subclassed QGraphicsItem not getting mouse events when used as module

Tags: pyqt, mouseevent, subclass, pyside

I'm using Pyside to create an interactive subclassed QGraphicsView - containing some subclassed QGraphicsItems.
It works well in its own module and receives mouse events.

But when used as a module from another file, and incorporated into another Layout - my mouse events are not being triggered.
However .itemChange is working.
Everything except the mouse events.
I am not using tracking events such as hover. I am using mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent.

I have seen c++ responses about setting "setMouseTracking" but this is for widgets and my QGraphicsItems have been added as items not widgets. So when I call this funcion it tells me it doesn't exist for items. Also that seems to be for hover type of events - which I am not needing.
I believe I am subclassing properly and I pass on the events to the parent class. As I said at the start - my code works fine in a standalone file.

Any ideas what I've forgotten to do ?

Here is the standalone - working program:
Save as test_subclass_module.py

```
import sys
import weakref
import math
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui



###
class Edge(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    Type = QtGui.QGraphicsItem.UserType + 2

    def __init__(self, sourceNode, destNode):
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.__init__(self)
        #
        self.sourcePoint = QtCore.QPointF()
        self.destPoint = QtCore.QPointF()
        self.setAcceptedMouseButtons(QtCore.Qt.NoButton)
        self.source = weakref.ref(sourceNode)
        self.dest = weakref.ref(destNode)
        self.source().addEdge(self)
        self.dest().addEdge(self)
        self.set_index()
        self.adjust()

    def type(self):
        return Edge.Type

    def sourceNode(self):
        return self.source()

    def setSourceNode(self, node):
        self.source = weakref.ref(node)
        self.adjust()

    def destNode(self):
        return self.dest()

    def setDestNode(self, node):
        self.dest = weakref.ref(node)
        self.adjust()

    def set_index(self):
        self.setToolTip(self.source().label)

    def adjust(self):
        # do we have a line to draw ?
        if  self.source() and self.dest():
            line = QtCore.QLineF(self.mapFromItem(self.source(), 0, 0), self.mapFromItem(self.dest(), 0, 0))
            length = line.length()
            if length > 20:
                edgeOffset = QtCore.QPointF((line.dx() * 10) / length, (line.dy() * 10) / length)
                self.prepareGeometryChange()
                self.sourcePoint = line.p1() + edgeOffset
                self.destPoint   = line.p2() - edgeOffset
            else: # want to make sure line not drawn
                self.prepareGeometryChange()
                self.sourcePoint = self.destPoint 

    def boundingRect(self):
        # do we have a line to draw ?
        if not self.source() or not self.dest():
            return QtCore.QRectF()
        else:
            extra = 1
            return QtCore.QRectF(self.sourcePoint,
                                 QtCore.QSizeF(self.destPoint.x() - self.sourcePoint.x(),
                                               self.destPoint.y() - self.sourcePoint.y())).normalized().adjusted(-extra, -extra, extra, extra)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        if self.source() and self.dest():
            # Draw the line itself.
            line = QtCore.QLineF(self.sourcePoint, self.destPoint)
            if line.length() > 0.0:
                painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))
                painter.drawLine(line)

###
class Node(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    Type = QtGui.QGraphicsItem.UserType + 1

    def __init__(self, graphWidget, time, temp, pos):
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.__init__(self)

        self.graph = weakref.ref(graphWidget)
        self.edgeList = []
        self.set_index(pos)
        self.newPos = QtCore.QPointF()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        self.setCacheMode(self.DeviceCoordinateCache)
        self.setZValue(-1)
        #
        self.temp = temp
        self.time = time
        x,y = self.map_temptime_to_pos()
        self.setPos(x,y)
        self.marker = False


    def type(self):
        return Node.Type

    def addEdge(self, edge):
        self.edgeList.append(weakref.ref(edge))

    def set_index(self, index):
        self.index = index
        self.label = "Step %d" % index
        self.setToolTip(self.label)

    def get_prev_edge(self):
        index = 1000
        edge = False
        for e in self.edgeList:
            sn = e().source().index
            dn = e().dest().index
            if sn < index:
                index = sn
                edge = e
            if dn < index:
                index = dn
                edge = e
        return edge

    def get_next_edge(self):
        index = -1
        edge = False
        for e in self.edgeList:
            sn = e().source().index
            dn = e().dest().index
            if sn > index:
                index = sn
                edge = e
            if dn > index:
                index = dn
                edge = e
        return edge

    def map_temptime_to_pos(self):
        x = self.time * self.graph().graph_width_ratio
        y = self.graph().size[3] - self.temp * self.graph().graph_height_ratio
        return (x,y)

    def boundingRect(self):
        adjust = 2.0
        return QtCore.QRectF(-10 - adjust, -10 - adjust,
                             22 + adjust, 23 + adjust)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.drawLine(QtCore.QLineF(6,-40,6,-2))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.lightGray)
        painter.drawEllipse(-10, -10, 20, 20)
        gradient = QtGui.QRadialGradient(0, 0, 22)
        if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Sunken: # selected
            gradient.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.darkGreen).lighter(120))
        else:
            gradient.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.blue)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(gradient))
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 0))
        painter.drawEllipse(-6, -6, 12, 12)


    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            for edge in self.edgeList:
                edge().adjust()
        return QtGui.QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, value)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.graph().inhibit_edit:
            self.update()
            print "Node pressed"
            QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if not self.graph().inhibit_edit:
            self.update()
            print "Node released"
            #
            QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)



###
class GraphWidget(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
        self.size = (-30, 30, 600, 400)
        #
        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        scene.setItemIndexMethod(QtGui.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        scene.setSceneRect(self.size[0],self.size[1],self.size[2],self.size[3])
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorViewCenter)
        #
        self.maxtemp = 300
        self.maxtime = 160
        self.nodecount = 0
        self.calc_upper_limits()
        #
        self.scale(0.8, 0.8)
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Elastic Nodes"))
        self.inhibit_edit = False

    def calc_upper_limits(self):
        self.toptemp = (self.maxtemp / 100 + 1) * 100
        self.toptime = (int(self.maxtime) / 30 + 1) * 30
        self.graph_width_ratio = float(self.size[2]) /self.toptime
        self.graph_height_ratio = float(self.size[3]) / self.toptemp

    def add_node(self, time, temp, marker=False, pos=-1):
        self.nodecount += 1
        scene = self.scene()
        # Insert Node into scene
        node = Node(self, time, temp, self.nodecount)
        scene.addItem(node)
        # Insert new edges
        nodes = self.get_ordered_nodes()
        if len(nodes) > 1:
            e = Edge(nodes[-2], node)
            scene.addItem(e)
        # cleanup edge tooltips
        for n in self.get_ordered_nodes():
            edges = n.edgeList
            for e in edges:
                e().set_index()

    def get_ordered_nodes(self):
        nodes = [item for item in self.scene().items() if isinstance(item, Node)]
        nodes.sort(key=lambda n: n.index)
        return nodes

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Plus:
            self.scaleView(1.2)
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Minus:
            self.scaleView(1 / 1.2)
        else:
            QtGui.QGraphicsView.keyPressEvent(self, event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "GraphWidget mouse"
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self.scaleView(math.pow(2.0, -event.delta() / 240.0))

    def scaleView(self, scaleFactor):
        factor = self.matrix().scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor).mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)).width()
        if factor < 0.07 or factor > 100:
            return
        self.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        sceneRect = self.sceneRect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = GraphWidget()
    widget.add_node(0,    25)
    widget.add_node(30,  100)
    widget.add_node(60,  200)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the parent program - which does not get the mouse events:
Called test_toplevel.py

```
# import user interface etc
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from test_tabs_ui import Ui_Form
from test_subclass_module import *

import sys

Programs = {"Gen13": {"steps": [[0, 0, 0], [0, 30, 30], [0, 60, 60], [0, 77, 77]]
                      }}


###-----------------------------------------------------------
### The dialog
class Nusku_tab_Add_kiln(QtGui.QWidget):
    """ Create dialog to add/delete kilns from controlled kilns """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Get the UI loaded
        super(Nusku_tab_Add_kiln, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.current = Programs['Gen13']
        # draw program in graphicsView
        # swap out the standin
        self.ui.graphLayout.removeWidget(self.ui.graphicsView)
        self.ui.graphicsView.setParent(None)
        self.ui.graphicsView.deleteLater()
        self.graph = GraphWidget()
        self.ui.graphLayout.addWidget(self.graph)
        self.draw_graph()

    def choose_program(self):
        pass

    def draw_graph(self):
        graph = self.graph
        graph.inhibit_edit = True
        steps = self.current['steps']
        for s in steps:
            print s
            graph.add_node(s[1],s[2])

###------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = Nusku_tab_Add_kiln()
    prog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For sake of completeness. Here is the ui file it imports:
test_tabs_ui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test_tabs.ui'
#
# Created: Wed Dec 05 15:20:02 2012
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.14 running on PySide 1.1.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(595, 540)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.Tab_Program = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.Tab_Program.setObjectName("Tab_Program")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.Tab_Program)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame_graph_status = QtGui.QFrame(self.Tab_Program)
        self.frame_graph_status.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_graph_status.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_graph_status.setObjectName("frame_graph_status")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_graph_status)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.frame_program = QtGui.QFrame(self.frame_graph_status)
        self.frame_program.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_program.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_program.setObjectName("frame_program")
        self.graphLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_program)
        self.graphLayout.setContentsMargins(-1, 0, -1, 0)
        self.graphLayout.setObjectName("graphLayout")
        self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.frame_program)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.graphLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.frame_program)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_graph_status)
        self.widget_prog = QtGui.QWidget(self.Tab_Program)
        self.widget_prog.setObjectName("widget_prog")
        self.prog_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.widget_prog)
        self.prog_layout.setContentsMargins(4, 4, 4, 4)
        self.prog_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.prog_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.prog_layout.setObjectName("prog_layout")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget_prog)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Tab_Program, "")
        self.Tab_alarms = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.Tab_alarms.setObjectName("Tab_alarms")
        self.alarms_tab_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.Tab_alarms)
        self.alarms_tab_layout.setObjectName("alarms_tab_layout")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Tab_alarms, "")
        self.Tab_settings = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.Tab_settings.setObjectName("Tab_settings")
        self.settings_tab_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.Tab_settings)
        self.settings_tab_layout.setObjectName("settings_tab_layout")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Tab_settings, "")
        self.Tab_pid = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.Tab_pid.setObjectName("Tab_pid")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.Tab_pid)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.scrollArea_2 = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.Tab_pid)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 569, 494))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.PID_tab_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.PID_tab_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.PID_tab_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.PID_tab_layout.setObjectName("PID_tab_layout")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Tab_pid, "")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.tabWidget, self.graphicsView)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.graphicsView, self.scrollArea_2)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.graphicsView.setToolTip(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "decimal point", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.graphicsView.setStatusTip(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Accuracy can be increased at lower temperatures", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Tab_Program), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Program", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Tab_alarms), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Alarms", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Tab_settings), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Settings", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Tab_pid), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "PID", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: Yes: you forgot to post the code.

Comment: Umm, you set `inhibit_edit` to `False` in `test_toplevel.py`, which kind of makes your `Node`s to ignore mouse events?

Comment: my life is a tragedy... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there is an answer - which reasonably asks me to delete my answer - I have to answer the question with my own answer to close it. After waiting 3 days... hopefully I can delete it - but probably not as it has an answer..

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and tried your application and saw it more or less working
(although the cursor position gets wrong in test_toplevel.py).

After removing `graph.inhibit_edit = False` also the cursor stays right.

So is the problem already solved? Then it would be very helpful to remove your
question or mak it as resolved. Or please clarify the question.

Comment: you answered it-- so I can't delete it...